# Merging objects in Soft Body

Tags: soft-body

I want to create and animate dice, but I have no idea how to merge the dice with numbers, so that the numbers can roll along with the dice. I tried parenting, ctrl+j and boolean, but non of these work. Parented numbers just stay in air, ctrl+j and boolean fall off as soon as dice hits the ground. That's how it looks: https://i.imgur.com/ftSwr4K.gifv

How can I make the dice as one object so I can animate the roll?

Comment: weird, if you parent an object (like your number) to your falling object, it should follow, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I found a way to fix it. I don't know why I was using soft body with dice, as it should be solid. Changing to rigid body fixed this.

Comment: oh yes of course ah ah  ;)